# Creating a Visual Studio Extension to auto-document - for fixing StyleCop errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I am creating an extension for fixing StyleCop errors. The most commonly found issue is that of documentation that is not proper/valid.

I was hoping to find a way to automatically trigger the documentation handler - that is, adding `///` would generate the documentation - or triggering an external extension's command like GhostDoc's `Document This` command which is shown on the page to document the file automatically.

Can anyone let me know if it is even possible to do this?

I have taken a look at the code for Visual Studio Sample Extensions at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/archive/2014/05/30/vs-2013-sdk-samples-released.aspx but I was unable to find any of them close to what I wanted.

I am unable to find good documentation for such stuff on MSDN either.

Answer (score 0):

See:

HOWTO: Manipulate a code or form designer file from a Visual Studio add-in
http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/

You can use the automation model (EnvDTE) even from a package:

HOWTO: Get an EnvDTE.DTE instance from a Visual Studio package.
http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages/